# Running out of ways to add a sound file in java

Tags: java

The trouble I'm having now is that I want to insert a sound within the explosion class, specifically in the run function. I have tried a number of ways to get the .WAV sound file to play but all of them failed.

Explosion:

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Explosion implements Runnable {

```
ColoredBallPanel myPanel;
private JLabel img_label;
private ImageIcon imageIcon; // The explosion GIF
private int x_position; // The x position of the GIF.
private int y_position; // The Y position of the GIF.
private final int img_display_time = 650;

public Explosion(ColoredBallPanel panel, int x, int y) {
    super();
    myPanel = panel;
    x_position = x;
    y_position = y;

    my_GIF();
}

/**
 * Adds the GIF to the panel relative to where the balls have collided.
 */
public void my_GIF() {
    imageIcon = new ImageIcon(
            "C:\\Users\\Oscar\\Desktop\\Bangor Uni Y2 S1\\ICP-2150-0 Advanced Java Programming 201819\\Lab9\\explo.gif"); // sets
                                                                                                                            // the
                                                                                                                            // image
                                                                                                                            // icon
    img_label = new JLabel();
    img_label.setBounds(x_position, y_position, 200, 200);// Add image at position x_position, y_position
    img_label.setIcon(imageIcon);
    myPanel.add(img_label);
}

/**
 * runs the thread on completion deletes the image
 */
@Override
public void run() {

    try {

        Thread.sleep(img_display_time); // Sleeps for a set amount of time.

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    img_label.setIcon(null); // Deletes the image.
    img_label = null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
      Explosion.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/sounds/" + url));
    clip.open(inputStream);
    clip.start();
```

There is a pretty good explanation here:  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info